# Laravel Excel: Store csv file only if array data is not empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm using [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.com/) in a project, and I want to store the data as CSV only if there is data. Unfortunately, LaravelExcel `array` method needs to return an array, and if the result is empty, it creates a file with the given file name without content. So I want to make the file only if there is data. Here is how I used it:

```
Excel::store(new Foo(), 'filename', 'storage_disk');
```

Comment: I haven't used this package.  However, if you are building your collection first to fill said new CSV just check for null on the collection.

Comment: There is a way to first check if data exists and then pass it to Excel::store, but I don't like this approach. I want the Foo to be responsible for returning data needed for CSV

Comment: Just took a couple min and looked at the package. It doesn't look like there is another option of doing this. When you instantiate the Foo function that brings back your collection there is no ability to look for null. The only way I could see doing it is wrapping the excel function in logic based on the Foo(). Not desirable but I don't see anything in the docs that will let you pass anything from the Foo() to and do logic there.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, It seems there isn't any better solution